# Why do I get error on the definition of a function that returns a unique_ptr to a an object of a template class?

Tags: c++

This works fine:

```
template <typename key_t>
class BST{
    struct node{
        node(const key_t mKey) : key(mKey){}

        key_t key;
        std::unique_ptr<node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<node> right;
    };

    //stuff

    //this function definition works fine here
    std::unique_ptr<node>& _find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<node> &curr){
        if(curr->left == nullptr)
        return curr;

        return _find_next_successor(curr->left);
    }


};
```

But when I try to implement _find_next_successor out of the class, I get an error:

```
template <typename key_t>
class BST{
    struct node{
        node(const key_t mKey) : key(mKey){}

        key_t key;
        std::unique_ptr<node> left;
        std::unique_ptr<node> right;
    };

    //stuff

    //definition
    std::unique_ptr<node>& _find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<node> &);

};

//implementation, I get error by the compiler
template <typename key_t>
std::unique_ptr<BST<key_t>::node> &
BST<key_t>::_find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<node> &curr){
    if(curr->left == nullptr)
        return curr;

    return _find_next_successor(curr->left);
}
```

```
C:\Users\m\Documents\TreeNode20.cpp:65:33: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Dp> class std::unique_ptr'
 std::unique_ptr<BST<key_t>::node> BST::_find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<node> &curr){
                                 ^

C:\Users\m\Documents\TreeNode20.cpp:65:33: error:   expected a type, got 'BST<key_t>::node'
C:\Users\m\Documents\TreeNode20.cpp:65:33: error: template argument 2 is invalid
C:\Users\m\Documents\TreeNode20.cpp:65:35: error: prototype for 'int BST<key_t>::_find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<BST<key_t>::node>&)' does not match any in class 'BST<key_t>'
 std::unique_ptr::node> BST<key_t>::_find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<node> &curr){
                                   ^
C:\Users\marco\Documents\TreeNode20.cpp:22:25: error: candidate is: std::unique_ptr<BST<key_t>::node>& BST<key_t>::_find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<BST<key_t>::node>&)
  std::unique_ptr<node>& _find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<node> &);
                         ^


Compilation results...
--------
- Errors: 5
- Warnings: 0
- Compilation Time: 0.70s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the keyword `typename` within the template parameter for the `unique_ptr` in the function definition:

```
template <typename key_t>
std::unique_ptr<typename BST<key_t>::node> & //missing keyword
BST<key_t>::_find_next_successor(std::unique_ptr<node> &curr){
...
}
```

The compiler needs that keyword to know that `node` is a nested type within `BST`.

Comment: Just note that the extra `typename` is required only because, in this context, `node` is a [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) since `BST<key_t>` depends on a template parameter `key_t`. The compiler needs a little extra help in resolving some ambiguities that dependent names present.